# SELECT * and SELECT COUNT(*) in one query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My SQL query looks like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories AS c
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT i.* 
                   FROM influencer_profiles AS i 
                   WHERE c.id = i.category_id
                   ORDER BY i.updated_at
                   LIMIT 2) AS i ON 1 = 1
INNER JOIN users AS u ON i.user_id = u.id
```

But I also want to count each `influencer_profile` for category to display how many `influencer_profile`s in each categories. How can I use `COUNT(*)` with selecting all columns?

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories AS c
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM influencer_profiles AS i 
                   WHERE c.id = i.category_id
                   ORDER BY i.updated_at
                   LIMIT 2) AS i ON 1 = 1
INNER JOIN users AS u ON i.user_id = u.id
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want a window function.  I note that you are using `left join` in one place and the `inner join` is undoing it.

So, I am thinking:

```
SELECT c.*, i.*, u.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.id) as category_cnt
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT i.*
      FROM influencer_profiles AS i 
      WHERE c.id = i.category_id
      ORDER BY i.updated_at
      LIMIT 2
     ) i
     ON 1=1 LEFT JOIN
     users u 
     ON i.user_id = u.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But `category_cnt` in your query returns 2 for all categories(because of limit 2). I am sorry that my question wasn't clear. What I want is to count all `influencer_profile` in every categories, not from sub `SELECT`.

Comment: @freewebwithme . . . That seems reasonable to me.  You haven't provided sample data, desired results, or a real definition of what an influencer is.

Comment: How can I provide sample data? Is kind of screen shot of influencer_profile table?